# Still cannot find google action using Action SDK on Google Home App

Tags: actions-on-google, google-smart-home

I am developing a Google Smart Home App, and I follow the official development document.

1. Create my project in Google Console
2. 'gactions update --action_project action.json --project {myproject}'
3. Complete the necessary information,including App Information, Account Linking;
4. 'gactions test --action_project action.json --project {myproject}'

I have tried many times, even I used the other accout, and created it. But the result was same that my smart home app still not appear in my google home.

Someone said they created their app, and it would appear in Home Control section like [test]{project_name} after 'gactions test'. But it not work for me. It is very frustrated. And This step has blocked my further work for many days.

Further more, I want to confirm the following question:

1. When I created my smart home app, the section is like this:

Actions added from Actions SDK

Actions:  (this place is emtpy, is it normal? or lack of something like agent or else)

2. The Smart Home App in test mode, it is required that voice-only conversations with the Google Home speaker, or directly appear in Google Home App after 'gactions test'?

Any help will be appreciated!

My action.json: { "actions": [{ "name": "actions.devices", "deviceControl": { }, "fulfillment": { "conversationName": "automation" } }], "conversations": { "automation" : { "name": "automation", "url": "https://xxxxx" } } }

Answer (score 0):

running it the first time could be a bit painful. Below is what I do to get it working.

1. Make sure you have filled in all details on the action console.
2. Click on the Test button to start your app.
3. From the simulator, type Talk to . It might ask you to login.
4. If you can see the response from your app. Then it should work on your google home.
5. Please note that your test app will expire if you leave it idle for too long. You need to click on the test button to run it again or your google home won't be able to lunch your app.

Also, in your action.json, if you are pointing your intend to a webhook, please make sure your webhook is accessible from google.

Comment: Thank you very much! I am developing a Google Smart Home App. It seems that It is not required speak 'talk to {myproject}' to Google Assitant for invocation. And Normally, it will appear in Home Control section.The following is my action.json:{
  "actions": [{
    "name": "actions.devices",
    "deviceControl": {
    },
    "fulfillment": {
      "conversationName": "automation"
    }
  }],
  "conversations": {
    "automation" :
    {
      "name": "automation",
      "url": "https://xxxxx"
    }
  }
}

Comment: Oh, sorry. I wasn't aware you are building an smart home app. I can't help you with that as I haven't done one before. Hope someoneelse here will be able to help you out.